# How to remove a node from a binary tree?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I need to write a method to delete a node from a binary tree. I tried reading and making use of other people's questions, kind of helped. Thing is I get some errors. I'm kind of confused.

Here is the code:

```
 String delete(int k)
{
    BSTNode maxfromleft = null;
    BSTNode n = getNode(k);
    BSTNode n1 = n;
    if(n == null) 
        return null;
    if (k < node.getKey())
        n.left.setValue(delete(n.left.getKey()));

    else if(k > node.getKey()){
        n.right.setValue(delete(n.right.getKey()));
    }
    else{
        if(n.right != null && n.left != null){
            maxfromleft = max(n.left);
            n.left.setValue(delete(n.left.getKey()));
            n.setValue(maxfromleft.getValue());
        }
        else if(n.right == null){
            n = n.left;
            return n1.getValue();
        }
        else if(n.left == null){
            n = n.right;
            return n1.getValue();
        }
    }
    return n.getValue();
}


private BSTNode max(BSTNode n) {
    if (n == null)
        return null;
    if (n.right != null)
        return max(n.right);
    return n;
}
```

I get a NullPointerException error at this line:

```
        n.left.setValue(delete(n.left.getKey()));
```

why?
How can I fix this?

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: When I get to the line of error it says "Source not found."

Comment: If you're in an IDE you should be able to attach the Java source. At least on my computer, it's sitting in JAVA_HOME.